# BeautifulSoup's "find" acting inconsistently (bs4)

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm scraping the NFL's website for player statistics. I'm having an issue when parsing the web page and trying to get to the HTML table which contains the actual information I'm looking for. I successfully downloaded the page and saved it into the directory I'm working in. For reference, the page I've saved can be found [here](http://www.nfl.com/stats/categorystats?tabSeq=0&statisticCategory=PASSING&conference=null&season=1998&seasonType=REG&d-447263-s=PASSING_YARDS&d-447263-o=2&d-447263-n=1).

```
# import relevant libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("1998.html"))
result = soup.find(id="result")
print result
```

I found that at one point, I ran the code and result printed the correct table I was looking for. Every other time, it doesn't contain anything! I'm assuming this is user error, but I can't figure out what I'm missing. Using "lxml" returned nothing and I can't get html5lib to work (parsing library??).

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should read the contents of your file before passing it to BeautifulSoup.

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("1998.html").read())
```

Second, verify manually that the `table` in question exists in the HTML by printing the contents to screen. The `.prettify()` method makes the data easier to read.

```
print soup.prettify()
```

Lastly, if the element does in fact exist, the following will be able to find it:

```
table = soup.find('table',{'id':'result'})
```

A simple test script I wrote cannot reproduce your results.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def test():
    # The URL of the page you're scraping.
    url = 'http://www.nfl.com/stats/categorystats?tabSeq=0&statisticCategory=PASSING&conference=null&season=1998&seasonType=REG&d-447263-s=PASSING_YARDS&d-447263-o=2&d-447263-n=1'

    # Make a request to the URL.
    conn = urllib.urlopen(url)

    # Read the contents of the response
    html = conn.read()

    # Close the connection.
    conn.close()

    # Create a BeautifulSoup object and find the table.
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
    table = soup.find('table',{'id':'result'})

    # Find all rows in the table.
    trs = table.findAll('tr')

    # Print to screen the number of rows found in the table.
    print len(trs)
```

This outputs `51` every time.

Comment: @Jafar You're welcome. Let me know if this helps or not. If need be I can expand on the answer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.

1. Why was it still showing up without using the read method? Regardless, I've modified it now.

2. I have verified that it does exist. I can see the html tags (<tr><td>) and their associated values which appear in the table I'm looking to parse. But, it does not appear when using .prettify().

3. Thanks, using this.

Re-ran - produced correct results. Re-ran again, produced the wrong results. Closed and re-opened everything, returned nothing once again. Sorry for the terseness, ran out of characters! (and multiple edits!!)

Comment: The strangest part of this is how it *sometimes* produces the desired results. You don't by chance have some other process that causes the contents of `1998.html` to change do you?

Comment: `.read()` isn't *a hard requirement*, but it is better form. It will work either way.

Comment: Exactly, that is what I don't get!

Nope - no other changes to 1998.html.

I'm doing this in iPython Notebook, if that makes a difference...

Comment: Is the code in your question all of the code or is there more before/after the included snippet?

Comment: Here is all the code:

    # convert the HTML files to DataFrames

# import relevant libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open("1998.html").read(), 'lxml')
result = soup.find('table',{'id':'result'})
print result
#print soup.prettify()'

That's all I'm running at this point...

Comment: See my updated answer. I can't seem to reproduce this, even when I'm collecting the same data you are.

Comment: Thanks. How are you running this? In iPython Notebook I'm getting an error when you assign a value to trs, saying "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'".

Would like to try using Terminal and TextWrangler - having an issue with it recognizing my bs4 module. Looking into that then will try it there.

Comment: Are you making an HTTP request or reading from file still? If you're reading from file, try it out using my example. It worked every time for me.

Comment: HTTP request. I have a feeling that iPython Notebook may be the problem.

Comment: It might be, but I don't see how. The HTML response should be the same regardless of where its coming from. Have you tried running your code in the interactive interpreter or somewhere else?

Comment: Figured out what was causing the issue with TextWrangler + Terminal. Copied and pasted your code directly into TextWrangler, saved it and ran it. Same error the first time. Returned 16 four times. Then had the same error again... I think I may just create a new user account and run it there.

Comment: Yeah, I'd give that a shot. Sorry. I wish I could help you more, but this code works perfectly for me every time. I can't fix a problem I can't reproduce, ya know?

Comment: Completely understand, thanks for all your help thus far! Narrowing down the issue is super helpful!!

Comment: Creating a new account worked! I then downloaded iPython and it still had the issue, so it looks like I messed something up in my main account's installation of Python and iPython.

Thanks for your help! Marked as answered. My upvote doesn't show up, new user :-/